# How to return all data within a class

Tags: c++, class

I'm new to c++ (and coding in general) and love learning it. I'm currently studying classes and I would like to figure out a way to print a whole class in one go rather than recalling individual parts. I posted on stackReview and I got this response to my code: `friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, Book const& b) { return s << b.title << b.author << b.pages;}`. I'm not exactly sure how I print this though. Please see my code below:

```
#include <iostream>

class Book{

    public:
        std::string title;
        std::string author;
        int pages;
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, Book const& b) { return s << b.title << b.author << b.pages;}
    Book(std::string aTitle, std::string aAuthor, int aPages){
        title = aTitle;
        author = aAuthor;
        pages = aPages;
                }
};


int main(){
    Book book1("Harry Potter", "JK Rowling", 500);
    Book book2("Lord of the Rings", "Tolkein", 750);
    Book book3("Hunger Games", "Author for Book", 250);
    std::cout<<book1.title;
    std::cout<<book2.author;
    std::cout<<book3.pages;

//Currently I'm  calling from the class by doing the above. But it'd be great to learn how
//to recall a whole class in one go, rather than doing `std::cout<<book1.title;`.

return 0;
}
```

Please let me know how to recall a whole class.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: The `operator<<` function you were advised to create lets you just write `std::cout << book1`, and it will call the function to print out all the fields in the class. This is called "operator overloading".

Answer (score 0):

I see you've added `friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, Book const& b) { return s << b.title << b.author << b.pages;}` in your class. This means you have overloaded the `<<` operator.

What you can do is `std::cout<<book1;` instead of having to print each property like you are doing now.

Check out [this site](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/overloading-stream-insertion-operators-c/) to learn more about operator overloading.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass your instances to cout:

```
int main() {

    Book book1("Harry Potter", "JK Rowling", 500);
    Book book2("Lord of the Rings", "Tolkein", 750);
    Book book3("Hunger Games", "Author for Book", 250);

    std::cout<<book1<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<book2<<std::endl;
    std::cout<<book3<<std::endl;
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The standard way is to create a function inside the class that will print all the data in the way you want.

```
class Book{

    public:
        std::string title;
        std::string author;
        int pages;
        friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& s, Book const& b) { return s << b.title << b.author << b.pages;}
        Book(std::string aTitle, std::string aAuthor, int aPages){
            title = aTitle;
            author = aAuthor;
            pages = aPages;
        }
        void printData(){
            std::cout<<title;
            std::cout<<author;
            std::cout<<pages;
        }
};
```

The function can be called from an object. eg: `book1.printData()`

Comment: This seems to be missing the point of providing the `operator<<` overload, although it does work of course.

Comment: Cheers pal. Appreciate it

Comment: why do you need both, the `operator<<` and `printData` ?